# Two functions that are derivatives of each other

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is there a pair of functions such that:

1. $D f(x) = g(x)$
2. $D g(x) = f(x)$
3. The functions are not the same function (without this 0 and $e^x$ would work)

In case that there isn't such pair of functions: What is the proof that such pair of functions can't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyperbolic sine and cosine satisfy this.

More generally, what you are looking is for $f$ to be a solution of the differential equation $f''=f$, and then you take $g=f'$.

So, in general, the functions that satisfy your equations are
$$
f(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}, \ \ g(x)=ae^x-be^{-x}
$$
for any choice of the coefficients $a,b$. For some particular cases, when $a=b=1/2$ you get $f(x)=\cosh x$; when $a=1/2$, $b=-1/2$ you get $f(x)=\sinh x$. You could also take $a=0$, $b=1$ to get $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose such functions $f$ and $g$ do exist. Then (letting $D$ be the differential operator) we have $$D^2f(x)=f(x)\\(D^2-1)f(x)=0$$
Since $f$ is not the zero function, then the only way this can happen is if $f$ is a linear combination of eigenfunctions of $D^2-1$ with eigenvalue $\pm 1$. (Why?) That is, $f(x)=ae^{x}+be^{-x}$ for some constants $a,b$. From this you can deduce $g(x).$